# Does Big Sur brick a MacBook Air 2014?

Tags: macos, install, big-sur

I want to install Big Sur on my MacBook Air 2014, but I’m concerned about reports that the installation of Big Sur did brick some older MacBook Pro. I couldn’t find any information regarding my MacBook Air 2014. Is it safe to install Big Sur on a MacBook Air 2014?

Comment: Why not link to a specific report? This is likely to be closed as unclear or opinionated if there aren’t any references or facts. It doesn’t really matter if hundreds of upgrades go well and yours fails. Basically asking the internet to guess if your Mac is healthy isn’t useful. Asking if Apple supports your model is generally useful.

Comment: I was under the impression that these reports are common knowledge. My MacBook is officially supported, but so are those that got bricked. Whatever happened to all the comments advising against upgrading before a new point release like 11.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211238

Supported MacBook 2014 Airs from the Apple knowledge base article:

> MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014)

> MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2014)

If the install caused issues with listed supported Macs, you'd be able to raise the issue with Apple.

Anything further would be speculation.

Comment: I’ve read about people who could not re-install anything after upgrading to Big Sur. They’ve completely bricked their machine. That is what concerns me.

Comment: If you're worried about an update, don't do the update. I'm afraid no one's going to be able to absolutely say any OS update is going to be 100% compatible, the only avenue for you is that if something did go wrong for any reason, if your machine is on the compatible list, Apple would book it in for a fix if it was caused by their OS.

Comment: Sure, I might have a claim against Apple if my MacBook gets bricked, but I’d rather not try to enforce that. I just want a smooth upgrade.

Comment: You shouldn't upgrade right now then, while there is doubt in your mind. According to the articles I could find about the issue, Apple are aware of the problems and are looking at a fix. It would be best to wait for an 11.1 release, and check the release notes on the Apple website. Only Apple will be able to provide any assurance of a fix for your MacBook model.